# Tracking Form Updates with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been working on a database for a little while here, and while I'm still kinda new to MS Access, I do know how to code some basic things.  Nevertheless, what I'm trying to do isn't so much needed as it is something that I would like to add in just to make the database easier to use.

What I've got right now is a form that will allow a user to put in first name, last name (UserID will concatenate both last and first names, respectively) and the password, but here's the thing: If a user opts to close out of the form before saving, I've successfully implemented the On Unload event to ask the user if they'd like to save said information before closing the program.  The issue is, it does that ANY TIME the form closes.  Is there some way I can have the Save Record button be tracked, or be able to track any sort of updates on the form itself?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two potential solutions (not in any order of preference):

1. If the form is as simple as you say (just 4 or 5 controls) then when it loads save the information in some "state" in your form. Then, in the `Form_Unload` event, check to see if the form content is different from the one in your state. If it is, prompt the user if they want to save the data, otherwise carry on and do nothing since there have been no changes. Of course, if the user at any time presses the "Save Record" button, then you'll also need to update your state to contain the latest saved information.
2. Another way is to keep a clean/dirty flag for each control that you are interested in (username control, password control, etc.) and that the user can type data into. Most/All controls have an event to track if the data inside them has changed. So use that event and set the dirty flag to True if any edits happen in each control. When the user presses the "Save Record" button, then the flags should become clean, since the information has been saved and is up-to-date. Again, in the `Form_Unload` event, check the flags and if any are dirty then prompt the user to save, otherwise carry on and do nothing.

Comment: Hmm...Sounds simple.  I'll be sure to try that then.  Just trying to get used to all the MS Access Properties that come with each control and object.  Still, will either of these affect the ComboBox that's used as a form of look-up for the user?  In a nutshell, the ComboBox lets the user see the list of registered users in the database, where upon, if they select one, they see the first name, last name, password, and user id, as well as a subtable of additional data related to said entry.  Can I also mark the sub-table with the dirty flag, too?

Comment: It's difficult to tell you with certainty what's best in your situation without seeing the whole thing first-hand. In theory yes, you can have a flag for any control. But you're really only interested in controls that the user can change directly. For example, if the table is read-only, then you don't have to map any changes to it, since those changes are instigated by the combo box, in your case. So you need to track the combo box changes only.